# min z under these constrains

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

$$\min_{x,z} \{  z  : z \geq x^TA_{i}x \; (i=1,\ldots,k), \; x^Tx=1\}$$
$x$ is a vector and $A_{i}, i=1,2,...k $ are given matrixes

Comment: Thank you for considering this problem. I am curious about the reason about the hardness. THX

Comment: $x^Tx=1$ is a nonconvex constraint, and very little information is given about $A_i$. The case $k=1$ is easy via the S-lemma. If $A_i$ are positive semidefinite you can write it as $\max\{x^Tx : x^TA_ix\leq t\}$ and solve it for different values of $t$ until the optimal objective value is $1$. CPLEX and Gurobi can now optimize nonconvex quadratic objectives over a convex quadratic domain.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable information. I really need to reconsider the problem.